# Pass parameter to callback function of gadget.io.makeRequest

Tags: javascript, opensocial

I would like to pass a parameter to the callback function of `gadget.io.MakeRequest`.
Is this at all possible?

```
function MyRequest(param){
...
gadget.io.makeRequest(url, callback, opt_params, param);
...
}

function callback(result,param)
{
    eval("param(result)");
}

if (a==1)
  MyRequest(mycbk1);
if (a==2)
  MyRequest(mycbk2);

function mycbk1(result){
  // handle results of makeRequest when a==1
}
function mycbk21(result){
 // handle results of makeRequest when a==1
}
```

Comment: what are the js files you imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to wrap your callback function in an anonymous function, like so:

```
function MyRequest(param){
    ...
    gadget.io.makeRequest(
        url, 
        function(result) { callback(result, param); }, 
        opt_params);
    ...
}
```

When the gadget request finishes, the anonymous function will be called with `result` as the only argument. The anonymous function subsequently calls your `callback` function with both `result` and `param` as arguments.